# Sign convention with the $AdS$ metric

Tags: differential-geometry, metric-tensor, ads-cft, conventions, anti-de-sitter-spacetime

One would say that $AdS_n$ satisfies the equations for the scalar curvature (R) and Ricci tensor ($R_{\mu \nu}$), $R = - \frac{n(n-1)}{L^2}$ and $R_{ab} = - \frac{n-1}{L^2}g_{ab}$.

- But do the signs in the above depend on the sign of the metric convention?

---

I am confused when I look at these two metrics,

- $ds_1^2 =  \frac{r^2}{Q^2}dt^2 - \frac{Q^2}{r^2}dr^2$
- $ds_2^2 = \left (    1 - \frac{\Lambda r^2}{3}    \right ) dt^2 - \frac{ dr^2 } { \left (  1 - \frac{\Lambda r^2}{3}  \right )  }$

Are both the above valid metrics of $AdS_2$? (with what sign of $\Lambda$?)

For the first one has, $R = 2/Q^2$ and $R_{ab} = \frac{1}{Q^2}g_{ab}$

For the second one has $R = - \frac{2\Lambda}{3}$ and $R_{ab} = -\frac{\Lambda}{3}g_{ab}$

Now I am not sure how to consistently define $L>0$ for these two metrics using the same formula for both!

Comment: For anti-de Sitter space, it depends how you choose to define $\Lambda$, i.e. if you absorb the $\pm$ in the definition. Regardless, the energy density of $AdS$ is always negative.

Comment: @JamalS Can you kindly elaborate a bit? (1) Are you saying that the "n" formulas quoted initially are metric sign convention independent? (2) Can you give a prescription to define L for the last 2 AdS_ metrics with any choice of sign of $\Lambda$? (I can't see any consistent choice!)

Comment: See the different parametrizations of $AdS$ space in [global coordinates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anti_de_Sitter_space#Global_coordinates) and  [Poincaré coordinates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anti_de_Sitter_space#Poincar.C3.A9_coordinates)

Comment: @Trimok I have seen these links - well - my "Q" metric is a Poincare coordinates AdS_2 in the time-positive convention. But to evaluate its "L" don't I need a sign reversed version of the Ricci tensor and scalar formula as given in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anti_de_Sitter_space#Geometric_properties

Comment: @Trimok Now with my $\Lambda$ metric what is going on? It seems to me that since it is in the time-positive convention I should use the sign reversed Ricci tensor and scalar formula as given in the link above - BUT for that to give any sensible value of "L" I need $\Lambda >0$. Right?  (so what is this metric for $\Lambda < 0$?) [BUT if $\Lambda <0$ then it seems to fit the time-positive version of the global coordinates that you linked to! - and thats getting confusing!]

Comment: @JamalS Two questions to add (1) Is there a way to write global AdS in cartesian coordinates? (2) Is the hyperbolic foliation of $AdS$ a global coordinates?

Comment: @user6818 :  The result for $R$, and $R_{ab}$ in function of $g_{ab}$ does not depend on the (time) convention. So you must have done an error. Finally, your $\Lambda$ has to be negative, the correspondance with Wikipedia is $-\Lambda/3 = \frac{1}{\alpha^2}$